# Regex to find all possible occurrences of text starting and ending with ~

Tags: java, regex

I would like to find all possible occurrences of text enclosed between two `~`s.

For example: For the text `~*_abc~xyz~ ~123~`, I want the following expressions as matching patterns:

1. `~*_abc~`
2. `~xyz~`
3. `~123~`

Note it can be an alphabet or a digit.

I tried with the regex `~[\w]+?~` but it is not giving me `~xyz~`. I want `~` to be reconsidered. But I don't want just `~~` as a possible match.

Comment: `(?=(~.*?~))` #overlapping_matches #lookahead

Comment: I used rubular[.]com to verify . Seems like the first ~*abc~ is not picked up by your regex.

Comment: @AbhishekAsh Your requirements and sample string/output are not in sync

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Can u plz explain ? How it is out of sync. I will go ahead and correct it.

Comment: "it can be an alphabet or a digit"
but `*_` is neither alphabet nor digit...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [**capturing inside a positive lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#overlapping) with the following regex:

> Sometimes, you need several matches within the same word. For instance, suppose that from a string such as `ABCD` you want to extract `ABCD`, `BCD`, `CD` and `D`. You can do it with this single regex:
>
> `(?=(\w+))`
>
> At the first position in the string (before the `A`), the engine starts the first match attempt. The lookahead asserts that what immediately follows the current position is one or more word characters, and captures these characters to Group 1. The lookahead succeeds, and so does the match attempt. Since the pattern didn't match any actual characters (the lookahead only looks), the engine returns a zero-width match (the empty string). It also returns what was captured by Group 1: `ABCD`
>
> The engine then moves to the next position in the string and starts the next match attempt. Again, the lookahead asserts that what immediately follows that position is word characters, and captures these characters to Group 1. The match succeeds, and Group 1 contains `BCD`.
>
> The engine moves to the next position in the string, and the process repeats itself for `CD` then `D`.

So, use

```
(?=(~[^\s~]+~))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dJ0dW8/1)

The pattern `(?=(~[^\s~]+~))` checks each position inside a string and searches for `~` followed with 1+ characters other than whitespace and `~` and then followed with another `~`. Since the index is moved only after a position is checked, and not when the value is *captured*, overlapping substrings get extracted.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/W0qkEm):

```
String text = " ~*_abc~xyz~ ~123~";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=(~[^\\s~]+~))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    res.add(m.group(1));
}
System.out.println(res); // => [~*_abc~, ~xyz~, ~123~]
```

Just in case someone needs a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Gl6JdW):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?=(~[^\s~]+~))')
test_str = " ~*_abc~xyz~ ~123~"
print(p.findall(test_str))
# => ['~*_abc~', '~xyz~', '~123~']
```

Comment: Your answer always amazes me

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Thanks for the answer. Was banging my head for quite a while on this. Meets my requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Try this `[^~\s]*`

This pattern doesn't consider the characters `~` and space (refered to as `\s`).

I have tested it, it works on your string, here's [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/iM6eF2/2).