# Regex matching all subsequences, repeating characters

Tags: regex, sequence, subsequence

For example lets take the sequence

```
"aaaaaa".
```

I want regex to match all subsequences, including repeating characters. Meaning the total count of subsequences should be 5, instead of 3.

Clarification:

Lets numerate our characters. Our sequence will look something like

```
"a1a2a3a4a5a6"
```

All subsequences are:

```
"a1a2", "a2a3". "a3a4", "a4a5", "a5a6"
```

Can I do that in regex? I am currently programming in Java and I know it is possible to develop an algorithm there, but I would like to avoid that for now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches can help you start.

Comment: I understand that this is possible within java, but it is going be quite messy with my current skills so I was asking if it is an option in regex, because it seems logical to me to have such an option. I'll edit to be more clear.

Comment: `(?=((a)\2))` - the values are in Group 1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, it works. However can you please explain how exactly. I looked up positive lookahead, but still can't understand how is your expression working exactly.

Comment: What is the programming language? What method are you using?

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer. It is a bit more complicated than what I used to close this question with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following  regex:

```
(?=((a)\2))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU5xH6/1)

The technique of capturing the overlapping substrings inside a positive lookahead is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331115/regex-to-find-all-possible-occurrences-of-text-starting-and-ending-with/36331260#36331260).

The difference is that you need to use 2 capturing groups: one is a "functional", technical, inner group to make sure we match two identical consecutive symbols, and the outer group (ID#1) that we can use to extract the values we need.